# how to change color of particular part of image in android java?

Tags: android

[This is image/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqYRy.png)

I want to change color of nails when I click on any color in the bottom. Please help me, I am stuck on it from 5 days
I have tried many codes from stack overflow but nothing worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

draw a shape and put it in an `ImageView` and place it where ever you want